# Nginx on Fedora 26: could not build optimal types_hash error message

Tags: nginx, fedora

I've installed Fedora and Ngnix, added all the configuration files for my local development, when I started to see this error

```
nginx: [warn] could not build optimal types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 2048 or types_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring types_hash_bucket_size
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

I found solutions saying that I should add `types_hash_bucket_size` to `nginx.conf`, but I've added it, removed the default one, removed both and added both, it insists on showing this error.

```
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile                            on;
    tcp_nopush                          on;
    tcp_nodelay                         on;
    keepalive_timeout                   65;

    # I tried leaving both, removing both and one of each. The error persists.
    types_hash_max_size                2048;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size      128;
```

`types_hash_max_size` was there by default when I installed nginx, though.

My files from `sites-enabled`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name devapi.hporder.com;

  root /home/gabriel/Sites/hp-order-system/workspace/api;

  client_max_body_size 10M;

  location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
    expires 30d;
  }

  location / {
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.10.1/html;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_param FF_BOOTSTRAP_ENVIRONMENT dev;
    fastcgi_param FF_BOOTSTRAP_CONFIG api/dev;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    # include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

    fastcgi_buffer_size 1024k;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 1024k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 1024k;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm on Fedora 27 and also receive this warning running Nginx out-of-the-box.  Could it be that the default configuration on Fedora is just wrong?

Answer (score 49):

On Fedora 25, I had this problem as well. `types_hash_max_size` was set to `2048` (nginx documentation indicate it defaults to `1024`).  I simply increased it to `4096` and nginx was happy (checked with `nginx -t`).

FWIW, in my configuration there is no setting related to the hash bucket size. It's just the default.

Answer (score 22):

Just open the file nginx.conf and just below **keepalive_timeout 65;**
add **types_hash_max_size 4096;**