# AWS Elastic Beanstalk [warn]: could not build optimal types_hash, you should increase types_hash_max_size..?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I have created an API and successfully deployed it via `AWS Elastic Beanstalk`.  The server is running and works as expected.

However, i downloaded the log file and the `error.log` shows `[warn] xxxx#xxxx: could not build optimal types_hash, you should increase types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring types_hash_bucket_size`

I am not sure what this warning means and how i fix it.  From my understanding this warning is related to `NGINX`, but that's about as much as i know.

I have looked around and it seems i may be able to resolve this through implementing a `.ebextensions` directory and then subsequent `<filename>.config` files but I don't know which files are needed, if any?

I am new to AWS, and to deploying projects in general, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Same issue here from /var/log/nginx/error.log
could not build optimal types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring types_hash_bucket_size

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67083364/2860358). It might help you resolve yours.

Comment: This is doable - are you using Amazon Linux 1 or Amazon Linux 2?

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved this by creating a configuration file within `.platform/nginx/conf.d`, say `10-types-hash.conf`:

```
# .platform/nginx/conf.d/10-types-hash.conf
types_hash_max_size 4096;
```

During the deployment process, Elastic Beanstalk copies this file to the `/etc/nginx/conf.d` directory which the main `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` configuration file includes within its `http` config block.

You may need to adjust the `4096` value. I tested by SSH-ing into an instance and upping the value then running `nginx -t` until the warning went away.